# Extract parameters from events triggered on a path in Firebase Database with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Functions to perform some back-end operations (e.g. counting/grouping statistics for the day). These functions are triggered when a certain events (update, create) happen on a path in the Firebase Database.

I am looking for a way to extract the path (and parameters) that has been updated/created such that I can target only a fraction. Specifically, if the path `path /messages/{pushId}/original` has been updated, I would like to extract the dynamic parameter `{pushId}` within my python function.

*As a recap:*

From the [Cloud Documentations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database#functions_firebase_rtdb-python), we can deploy a cloud function with the respective trigger as follows:

> The following gcloud command deploys a function that will be triggered
>   by update events on the `path /messages/{pushId}/original`:

```
gcloud functions deploy YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME \
  --trigger-event providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.update \
  --trigger-resource projects/YOUR-PROJECT-ID/instances/DATABASE-INSTANCE/refs/messages/{pushId}/original \
  --runtime RUNTIME
```

Within `main.py` we can then write a function that will be triggered when the above path has been updated:

```
import json
def hello_rtdb(data, context):
    """ Triggered by a change to a Firebase RTDB reference.
    Args:
        data (dict): The event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    trigger_resource = context.resource

    print('Function triggered by change to: %s' % trigger_resource)
    print('Admin?: %s' % data.get("admin", False))
    print('Delta:')
    print(json.dumps(data["delta"]))
```

The **missing link** is now how we use data, context to get the parameter `{pushId}`?

Comment: What about doing `context.resource.pushId`?

Comment: Sure that will work? As context.resource prints the path

Comment: No, not sure at all!... Was just trying to transfer the way it is done in Node.js to Python... (knowing there was a high probability it is not correct...). Sorry that I didn't indicate that it was a trial and error approach.