# Combining Firebase Data Triggers .create .update (and perhaps .remove) in Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We can write a cloud function (e.g. in python) as follows:

```
def some_function_update(data, context):
   # do some operations
   return True
```

And invoke it when a change on the Firebase Database happens. For instance, if the following node changes, with the dynamic parameters `yyyymmdd` and `alert_id`:

```
/alerts/{yyyymmdd}/{alert_id}
```

we can [capture this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198002/extract-parameters-from-events-triggered-on-a-path-in-firebase-database-with-clo) using `context.resource`:

```
trigger_resource = context.resource
temp_params = trigger_resource.split('/')
environment = temp_params[6]
client_id   = temp_params[7]
```

That aside, when we **deploy** this function to Cloud Functions, we have to execute the following in the terminal:

```
gcloud functions deploy some_function_update --runtime python37 --trigger-event providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.update --trigger-resource projects/_/instances/{INSTANE_NAME}/refs/alerts/{yyyymmdd}/{alert_id}
```

However, I noticed that the function `some_function_update` gets only triggered when there is an actual `.update`. However, when we add a new alert_id or day, the function does not get triggered.

I solved this by creating a new function that calls the other function:

```
some_function_create(data, context)
    some_function_update(data, context)
```

And deployed it using:

```
gcloud functions deploy some_function_create --runtime python37 --trigger-event providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.create --trigger-resource projects/_/instances/{INSTANE_NAME}/refs/alerts/{yyyymmdd}/{alert_id}
```

However, I find it cumbersome to have to deploy each time two functions and was therefore wondering if there is maybe a smarter way to do this in one shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it rather odd that this question hasn't received an answer yet. Perhaps there is something I'm missing, but firebase generally provides a `write` trigger for cloud functions. From the docs, this would be:
`providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.write`
Which would make your deployment code:

```
gcloud functions deploy some_function_create --runtime python37 --trigger-event providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.write --trigger-resource projects/_/instances/{INSTANCE_NAME}/refs/alerts/{yyyymmdd}/{alert_id}
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but from the docs it seems that this is indeed the solution